# Sampling Clock Offset estimation

Tags: sampling, estimation, synchronization, timing

I want to estimate sampling clock offset. I am currently referring this paper
" CRAMER-RAO BOUNDS FOR DATA-AIDED SAMPLING CLOCK OFFSET AND CHANNEL ESTIMATION ". Is there any other method to estimate? I also referred Lee's method, but it gives symbol timing. Is there a way to estimate sampling clock offset from timing error estimate?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a few different concepts (sampling clock offset, timing error, and symbol timing) that are really centered around the same thing. You really need to have a more specific question in order to get a good answer. A link to the paper would also help.

Comment: I want to estimate the sampling clock offset. I am referring this paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1327005&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D1327005. I wanted to know is there a simpler method to find the sampling clock offset. I tried the one method mentioned in this paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1327005&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D1327005 in the 3rd chapter. Its not giving me good estimate. Kindly provide me some clue regarding this

Comment: Link  to the second paper that isn't behind a paywall: http://www.supelec.fr/ecole/radio/icassp04.pdf

Comment: The second link that I provided is wrong, the correct one is here http://www.ece.usu.edu/grad/reports_theses_disseratations/2008/rodriguez_ana_a_paniagua/report.pdf. I tried estimating sampling frequency ratio using spectral estimation method but it isn't giving me good estimate. Is there a method to estimate the sampling clock offset or symbol rate offset?